# regression test on databases (blackbox)

Tags: testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

I have a system with a very complex behavior, which have already being manually tested by a QA professional.

I'm currently interested on running a regression test for the new version being developed. So, basically, my idea is to put a set of inputs on a database, run the old version and save the output. Then do the same with the new version and compare the output.

Somethings will change, though. For instance, fields depending on the current date, or ids of the tables (if they use sequences and aren't being run on a sandboxed database). Some ids of relations will also change.

Any hints on which framework could help me doing this kind of database-based regression test?